# Best way to set up logging for a Java Library that will be shared among many projects?

Tags: java, logging

**If I was creating a new java project that is going to be a library that will be used by multiple projects, what is the best way to set up the logging in it?**

Essentially the issue came up because everybody uses different logging libraries for there projects (log4j, common-logging, etc.) and I do not want to make it difficult for others to use what ever they want when they use my library.

The goal is to provide logging for the classes in my library, while providing a painless way for other projects that use it to use what ever logging framework they want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are wanting is [SLF4J](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLF4J).

> The separation of the client API from the logging backend reduces the
>   coupling between an application and any particular logging framework.
>   This can make it easier to integrate with existing or third-party code
>   or to deliver code into other projects that have already made a choice
>   of logging backend.

Answer (score 2):

Use slf4j (probably a better option than commons-logging, but that could work too). It'll adapt to whatever the individual projects are using.