# Which SLF4J logging dependency to use in a library

Tags: java, gradle, logging, slf4j

I am writing a tiny Java library and I want to know which of multiple SLF4J libraries to use, if I only want to add logging possibility to library and let end user choose logging framework type:

All I want is to be able to write `log.debug()` and `log.error()` across the code which mean to have SLF4J  bindings available.

Which dependency should I add to my library, there are a lot of things popping when one types SLF4J at https://mvnrepository.com

Comment: `slf4j.simple`.

Comment: @DanielWiddis this one: // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api
implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.6")

Comment: You use the `slf4j-api` in your library. Other users can use whatever logger they want with it.     If you need to enable simple logging yourself, such as for tests, use `slf4j-simple`: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple

Comment: The *slf4j* library is mere a façade for you to call throughout your app’s code. Then you plug in your choice of several logging libraries to actually log. A few libraries are direct implementations of slf4j interfaces. Most of these logging libraries require an adapter to mediate between the slf4j API and the API of the logging library. So your Question boils down to asking for a recommendation of which of the several logging libraries to use. And asking for software library recommendation is explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow. Try the sister site, Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.

Comment: @BasilBourque maybe I phrased this wrong. I am myself using log4j2 or logback, and I am happy with them. What I wanted to know is what dependecy should I ask to a library to allow it log messages. I dont care if end user will use JUL or logback, I just wanted to know which dependency to add, to enable this, as I heard from a friend, that I only need to add one when writing library, Since it was quite long time ago and he is on vacation now, I needed clarification and now I have it :)

Comment: @hetacz I see you've edited the question to simplify it, which makes it a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367103/best-way-to-set-up-logging-for-a-java-library-that-will-be-shared-among-many-pro

Comment: @DanielWiddis anyway I ended up with implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.19.0")
for lib and
testImplementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.19.0")
for tests, as Simple logger was too red for me, and I already had log4j2 config at hand.

Maybe I asked question a bit wrong, but since simple logger was no-no for me I took these 3 libraries I've since deleted from question) and checked which combination was working by trial & error

Anyhow, now I got what I wanted, and my lib is nearly ready for publish, Ill just wait for a friend to go back to review it.

Comment: You're locking your library users out of using logback by selecting a log4j api.  If you want more detailed logging levels this is your choice.   You don't need to use simple logger, you can use literally any logging framework you want.  SLF4J is the API front end to literally every other logging option.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Thank you, I had some issues with it not working properly witih log4j2 becuase such error appeared:

SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/C:/PATH/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.19.0/1a0c9615ba9fd5b96db8c1136afbef4394286e93/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.19.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

Comment: @DanielWiddis Interestingly I had same error when I upgraded WebDriverManager from 5.3.0 to 5.3.1 (https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/)

Comment: "Note that embedded components such as libraries or frameworks should not declare a dependency on any SLF4J binding but only depend on slf4j-api. When a library declares a compile-time dependency on a SLF4J binding, it imposes that binding on the end-user, thus negating SLF4J's purpose." - https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder

Comment: @aSemy So which do I use then not to become locked into one patrticular library, i want use to both be able to install slf simple, and if they get board switch to lobagback iwith no prolems

Comment: It depends on what you are making. If you are making a _library_ that will not be run independently, and will be consumed by libraries/applications, then _only_ use `slf4j-api` and _no_ binding (except in test classes - then you can include a binding because it won't 'leak' to consumers). This gives consumers the ability to choose the appropriate binding. If you are making an _application_ that will run independently, then use whatever slf4j binding you like.

Comment: @aSemy I am making a library for me and friends in company to use.
It must have a few test classes so I know it is working correctly.
Now I want to publish my repo so anyone could use it.

So your suggestion is:
`slg4j-api` to main (imp[lementation)
`xxx`  to  tests (testImplementastion)
`yyy` to rest of the programm (implementation)
right?

what shoudd be then xxx  and yyy if I want logback to be used?

Comment: The applications can use Logback binding https://stackoverflow.com/q/16660749/4161471

Comment: So to be 100% sure, I should add https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api
so any end user can use whaever logging facility she wants when she uses my library?

Comment: @hetacz TLDR: (1) If writing your own application, use whatever logger you want. If writing a library to be consumed by others, SLF4J maximizes compatibility at the cost of limiting features. (2) Your library should have a dependency on `slf4j-api`. That's it. (3) Users of your library, or you in your test framework for your library, can use any of the following: `log4j-slf4j-impl` (log4j2 with slf4j 1), `log4j-slf4j2-impl` (log4j2 with slf4j 2), `logback-classic`, `slf4j-reload4j`(security patched log4j1), `slf4j-log4j12` (vulnerable log4j1), `slf4j-jdk14` (JUL/JVM builtin), `slf4j-simple`.